# Oracle ADF Mobile Trinidad Faces not optimized for Android webkit browser (linuxwebkit)?

Tags: android, oracle-adf, trinidad

We are developing Mobile based application using Oracle ADF Mobile (Jdev R1). Trinidad Faces and JSF faces are rendering optimized on all smart phones (i.e. iPhone, Blackberry and windows) except Android (linuxwebkit) web browser. On Android web-browser page rendering as render in desktop browser.

thanks

-y

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are correct and the ADF Mobile developer guide for 11g R1 doesn't mention Android as a target platform: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e10140/toc.htm

However, JDeveloper 11g R2 does : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26098_01/web.1112/e16178/toc.htm

Just search for "Android" and you see what I mean. As you mention the base technology is Apache MyFaces Trinidad and the version of Trinidad thus determines the support for mobile devices.

Apparently JDeveloper 11g R2 uses the Trinidad libraries (JSF 2) that support the Android platform while JDeveloper 11g R1 does not.

Given that Trinidad 1.2 supports Android (though it might not have been tested as mentioned here: http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/mobile.html) you should be able to create your own skin for Android as documented here: http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/mobileSkinning.html

The RequestContext object in Trinidad returns the calling agent and you may want to check first if this returns Android. If it does then creating and applying a skin is easy to do.

Comment: thanks Frank for your reply. I have tested with Jdeveloper R2 too but getting same outcome.

Comment: Accordig to an answer by Shay Shmeltzer on the OTN forum for Oracle JDeveloper and ADF (https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=83) Android will be supported with the upcoming 11.1.1.7 release. So you seem to be correct that this is a not working thing yet.